# Migrating a value from an old field to a new field inside subdocuments in an array for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a task in each document of a mongo collection to migrate a value from one field to another new field.

An example of how the data initially looks:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec402eca370d5834f18b762"),
    "serial" : "SN12345678",
    "hostname" : "router1",
    "interfaces" : [
        {
            "name" : "eth0",
            "type" : "sfp",
            "connection": "isp"
            "ip" : "192.168.1.1/24",
            "gateway" : "192.168.1.254",
        },
        {
            "name" : "eth1",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection": "switch"
        }
    ],
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1vb402hnk370d9520d18b333"),
    "serial" : "SN87654321",
    "hostname" : "switch1",
    "interfaces" : [
        {
            "name" : "eth0",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection": "pc"
        },
        {
            "name" : "eth1",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection": "printer"
        }
    ],
}
```

I need to move the value from the "connection" field to the "conenction_to" field in each collection document. The final result should look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec402eca370d5834f18b762"),
    "serial" : "SN12345678",
    "hostname" : "router1",
    "interfaces" : [
        {
            "name" : "eth0",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection_to": {
                "device_type": "isp"
            }
            "ip" : "192.168.1.1/24",
            "gateway" : "192.168.1.254",
        },
        {
            "name" : "eth1",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection_to": {
                "device_type": "switch"
            }
        }
    ],
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1vb402hnk370d9520d18b333"),
    "serial" : "SN87654321",
    "hostname" : "switch1",
    "interfaces" : [
        {
            "name" : "eth0",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection_to": {
                "device_type": "pc"
            }
        },
        {
            "name" : "eth1",
            "type" : "copper",
            "connection_to": {
                "device_type": "printer"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

I have a microservice written in golang to work with the mongo database and inside the migration mechanism is implemented using the github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/ package (JSON is used as the request source for this package).

I did not have much experience with databases before and I had difficulties when working with nested documents inside an array for mongo.
First of all, I tried to solve the issue with the usual "update" and "set":

```
[
    {
        "update": "devices",
        "updates": [
            {
                "q": {"interfaces": {"$exists" : true}},
                "u": {
                    "$set": {
                        "interfaces.$[].connection_to": {
                            "device_type": "$connection"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "multi": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

...but I was unable to reuse the value from the old "connection" field.

I read the documentation and found information that aggregation must be used to reuse field values. I got a request like this:

```
[
    {
        "aggregate": "devices",
        "pipeline": [
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "interfaces" : { "$exists":true }
                }
            },
            {
                "$set":{
                    "interfaces": {
                        "$map":{
                            "input": "$interfaces",
                            "as": "interface",
                            "in": {
                                "name": "$$interface.name",
                                "type": "$$interface.type",
                                "ip": "$$interface.ip",
                                "gateway": "$$interface.gateway",
                                "connection_to": {
                                    "device_type": "$$interface.connection"
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$out": "devices"
            }
        ],
        "cursor": {}
    }
]
```

At the moment this option works, but there is a big problem. In fact, in every document I recreate the "interfaces" field and I have to explicitly specify all the fields of the attached document, otherwise there will be only a new field. This is a dangerous moment if in the future new fields appear in the document and there is a possibility of forgetting to specify new fields in the migration.

I would be grateful for help and advice on how to improve the query so that when migrating data to a new field, I do not lose the rest of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer. Use of *$mergeObjects*

```
[
    {
        "aggregate": "devices",
        "pipeline": [
            {
                "$match" : {
                    "interfaces" : { "$exists":true }
                }
            },
            {
                "$set":{
                    "interfaces": {
                        "$map":{
                            "input": "$interfaces",
                            "as": "interface",
                            "in": {
                                "$mergeObjects": [
                                    "$$interface",
                                    "connection_to": {
                                        "device_type": "$$interface.connection"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$out": "devices"
            }
        ],
        "cursor": {}
    }
]
```